# Google Cloud Run: Calling from outside GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to access a secure cloud run service. If I try from my machine with the SDK it works fine:

`curl --header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"`

However, I can not get it to work using the Python API using the same service account, I've tried using google-auth to get an access token but that gives me a 401 authentication error. This is the code I am using to try to get a token:

```
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']

creds, projects = google.auth.default(scopes=scopes)
auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
creds.refresh(auth_req)

# then using creds.token
```

Looking at the docs: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#calling_from_outside_gcp it says to follow the sample code here: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#iap_make_request-python I can't seem to follow the guide as it says to enable IAP but it seems that IAP is only for app engine and not cloud run?

Has anyone go any advice on this one?

Thanks

Comment: I've also tried using `AuthorizedSession` with the credentials https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#making-authenticated-requests this to gives a 401 error

Comment: Your code is generating an Access Token. Cloud Run requires an Identity Token. Were are you running this code at? This changes possible answers and required permissions.

Comment: I see now that I need an ID rather than Access token - i've used IDTokenCredentials to get that. Thanks

Comment: It also seems that I can not use a domain mapped to the cloud run service. Using the  `run.app` generated domain works using a mapped domain gives a 401 error.

Comment: You can use a custom domain. However, right now there seems to be an issue that is being investigated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK it seems that there is an IDTokenCredentials class that works for this as it uses Open ID Connect ID Tokens instead of OAuth 2.0 Access Tokens:

https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

service_url = 'example.com'
key_file = 'key.json'

credentials = service_account.IDTokenCredentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_file, target_audience=service_url)
authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
response = authed_session.get(service_url)
```

It's confusing as I don't see it in the docs and it's leading me to something else about IAP which I don't think is working with Cloud Run.

Comment: Great job, this helped me a lot! Can you accept the answer? ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to obtain your **ID token** and not use method from Dan's response there is an updated code:

```
import requests
import google.auth    
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

service_url = 'example.com'
key_file = 'key.json'

credentials = service_account.IDTokenCredentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_file, target_audience=service_url)
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(request)
token = credentials.token
print('ID Token:', token)
```